# Rotate curve in webgl

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, webgl

I approximate a curve with line segments:

```
for (i=1; i<=100; i=i+0.2)
    {
        arr = calculateCurve(i, 1, 1, 1, 1); //function returns an array of verticles
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
            prevArr[0]/scale,
            prevArr[1]/scale,
            prevArr[2]/scale,
            arr[0]/scale,
            arr[1]/scale,
            arr[2]/scale
        ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        gl.drawArrays(gl.LINES, 0, 2);

        prevArr = arr;

    }
```

I need to rotate the curve without using gl.drawArrays() again, because performance is extremely slow in this case.
I would create a huge buffer with 100 vertices, but I wonder if there's a way to redraw the scene just by changing rotation matrix in vertex shader.

Comment: [this article teaches how to rotate](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-rotation.html). If you follow it through to the articles after it you'll get to using a matrix to rotate.

Comment: Edited my answer so it fits your question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a "huge" buffer is not an issue here, the buffer is not even reaching 10kb in size ( If you use a different draw mode than `LINE` -> `LINE_LOOP` or `LINE_STRIP` ), however calling `glDrawArrays` multiple times is.

The right approach here is buffering the hole line. For this generate a `Float32Array` with a size which can hold all the floats to render. Then call `glBufferData` and `glDrawArrays` exactly one time.

If you don't change the line every frame you can also skip `glBufferData` after the first time you buffered the line.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean by rotate the curve. I see there are at least 2 interpretations. One is that you want the curve vertices to be in the same place but changing the viewer position so that you would be looking at the same curve at a different angle. The second is that you want a different curve shape every frame.

If what you want is 1), then all you have to do is send a matrix as uniform to the GPU and do `gl_Position = matrix * position` in the vertex shader. Doing this means you dont have to regenerate the vertex positions on the curve every frame.

If what you want is 2), then you need to come up with some math to calculate the position of each point on the curve in the vertex shader. How to do this is very case dependent and I think you need to show more code on how you calculate the positions on the curve.

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate vertices in WebGL by multiplying them by a rotation matrix.

For example this code will make a matrix that rotates vertices on the Z axis.

```
function rotationZ(angleInRadians) {

  var c = Math.cos(angleInRadians);
  var s = Math.sin(angleInRadians);

  return [
    c, s, 0, 0,
   -s, c, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1,
  ];
}
```

Here's a working example:

```js
function rotationZ(angleInRadians) {

  var c = Math.cos(angleInRadians);
  var s = Math.sin(angleInRadians);

  return [
    c, s, 0, 0,
    -s, c, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1,
  ];
}
    
// Using TWGL (twgljs.org) to keep the code small

  var gl = document.getElementById("c").getContext("webgl");
  // compiles shader, links and looks up locations
  var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, ["vs", "fs"]);

  // make some curve points
  points = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    var a = i / 100 * Math.PI * 2;
    var r = 0.5;
    points.push(
      Math.sin(Math.sin(a * 2.)) * r , 
      Math.cos(a) * r);
  }

  var arrays = {
    position: { numComponents: 2, data: points, },
  };
  // calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData for each array
  var bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, arrays);

  function render(time) {
    var uniforms = {
      u_matrix: rotationZ(time * 0.001),
    };

    gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
    // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
    twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
    // calls gl.uniformXXX, gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture
    twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, uniforms);
    // calls gl.drawArray or gl.drawElements
    twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo, gl.LINE_LOOP);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid blue; }
```

```html
<!-- 

note! I'm using a square canvas so I don't have to deal with aspect 
which would complicate the example

See the articles linked in the answer for details about aspect

-->
<canvas id="c" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/3.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<script id="vs" type="notjs">
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 u_matrix;

void main() {
  gl_Position = u_matrix * position;
}
</script>
<script id="fs" type="notjs">
precision mediump float;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(0,0,0,1);
}
</script>
```

[This article explains how rotation works](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-rotation.html) and the articles following it will transition into using matrices.